# Multiple option in select tag is not working in new window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, new-window

I want to select multiple items for this i added multiple but it is not working. 
Here is my code

```
<select class="form-control" name="columnValues[]" id="selectbox" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="I1">I1</option>
    <option value="I2">I2</option>
    <option value="I3">I3</option>
    <option value="I4">I4</option>
    <option value="I5">I5</option>
    <option value="I6">I6</option>
    <option value="I7">I7</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try below code and hold down the `Ctrl` (windows) / `Cmd` (Mac) button to select multiple options.  -

```
<select class="form-control" name="columnValues[]" id="selectbox" multiple> 
  <option value="">Select</option> 
  <option value="I1">I1</option> 
  <option value="I2">I2</option> 
  <option value="I3">I3</option> 
  <option value="I4">I4</option> 
  <option value="I5">I5</option> 
  <option value="I6">I6</option> 
  <option value="I7">I7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have tried it , it is not working .. ,
I am doing this in modal ,!!!  does that make any issue ???

Comment: @TrRavi there is no impact of modal on it, but do check the id and name should be unique.